# using NSSerlization to parse out contnent in URL encoded string

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I have this the following in a test.html file

```
<a href="http://playSound/?arguments=%7B%20soundID%3A%20%E2%80%9CDOG%E2%80%9D%2C%20foreground%3A%20false%2C%20loop%3A%20true%20%7D">SHOULD PLAY DOG IF YOU CLICK ME!</a>
```

I have the html already loaded on the iOS simulator, i would like to parse this and get DOG to pass it to my function, so it can play DOG, without hard coding it.

How can i do that? I am new to objective-C and need help with the code and the coding structure.

so far, i have only loaded the html content to the simulator, i have used URL encoded to get this url from JSON. My next steps are using NSSerlization to get the "DOG" out, parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the URL decoded arguments, you'll then have a string that looks like so:

```
{ soundID: “DOG”, foreground: false, loop: true }
```

Suppose you load this into an NSString, you can get an NSDictionary from it.

```
NSString *string = @"{ soundID: “DOG”, foreground: false, loop: true }";
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
```

Now, you can get the SoundID really easily.

```
NSString *soundID = dictionary[@"soundID"];
```

EDIT:

To retrieve the arguments GET variable, suppose you have the URL like so:

```
NSString *url = @"<a href="http://playSound/?arguments=%7B%20soundID%3A%20%E2%80%9CDOG%E2%80%9D%2C%20foreground%3A%20false%2C%20loop%3A%20true%20%7D">SHOULD PLAY DOG IF YOU CLICK ME!</a>";
```

You can split it up like so and get the URL decoded arguments to use with the code above:

```
NSArray *urlComps = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"arguments="];
NSString *arguments = [urlComps[1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""][0];
arguments = [arguments stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail, it really helps in understanding. I was wondering can i do it straight from the URL that i have above?

Comment: Of course.  You just need to retrieve the arguments.  I've updated my answer.